# Far Cry 3 Screen Covered with HTML

Tags: far-cry-3

[image: Screenshot] I have rebooted my PC and restarted my game several times and the problem persists. I am running Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried [verifying the game integrity with Steam?](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)

Comment: Looks like a lot of Steam related code. I'd do what @TimmyJim suggested. Also keep in mind that no where on the Steam page does it say that FC3 is Windows 10 compatible, and from some quick searches, it's commonly problematic on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @TimmyJim suggested verifying the game integrity seems to have fixed the problem